# Cardinality of a subset with two pairs $a_i = a_j$

Tags: probability

Let A = {$(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in S: a_i = a_j$ for at least one pair of $i \neq j$}

(# denotes cardinality in the following)

I can conclude that #$A^{c}$ is $r^{n}$ 
(Example 3 digits have $10^{3}$ combinations  [$0\dots 999$])

I also can conclude that #A = $r^{n-1}$

Now my textbook says taht #A $\leq r^{n-1}\frac{n(n-1)}{2r}$

The last term confused me. Is it a gausian summation? Why $\frac{n(n-1)}{2r}$ and what would be the lower estimate of $\frac{\#A^C}{\#S}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_{\{i,j\}} = \{(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in S : a_i = a_j\}$. Since $\#A_{\{i,j\}} = (\#S)^{n-1}$, we obtain $$\#A \leq \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \#A_{\{i,j\}} = \binom{n}{2}(\#S)^{n-1}.$$

Comment: n choose 2 because I can choose 2 combinations i,j, from n right?

Comment: @Bolz: that's it.